# TypeScript Msal-React PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-ad-msal

I am adding authentication to an app via msal-React.

My app is using `msalcontext` inside a component wrapped by `withMsal`:

```
function App(props: any) {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <Router msalContext={props.msalContext} />
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
      <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        <GenReLogin />
      </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
    </>
  )
}

export default withMsal(App)
```

In my router component I need to declare a type for the props, however I can't find anything in the msal docs to indicate what type this should be.

```
function Router({ msalContext }){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IMsalContext` interface.

```
import { IMsalContext } from "azure/msal-react";
function Router({ msalContext }: IMsalContext){...}
```

Please check this document for `IMsalContext`.

https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/interfaces/_azure_msal_react.IMsalContext.html

or

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/msal-react/imsalcontext?view=msal-js-latest

Comment: This functions properly but not i see the error `Property 'msalContext' does not exist on type 'IMsalContext'`

Comment: To be clear that error is happening on the `function App(props: any)` when I try to update that props with {msalContext}

Comment: could you please share your project or similar example project on CodeSandbox?